# How to patch a debian package?

Tags: makefile, build, debian, patch, dpkg

I used `apt-get source` to get a debian package $PKG-VERSION. I now have a folder `$PKG-VERSION/`, files `$PKG-VERSION.diff.gz`, `$PKG-VERSION.dsc` and `$PKG.orig.tar.gz`. If I understand it correctly, the diff file `$PKG-VERSION.diff` that is archived in `$PKG-VERSION.diff.gz` represents the difference between the upstream version in `.orig.tar.gz` and the debian version, and it has already been applied to files in the folder `$PKG-VERSION/`. But then I go look inside `$PKG-VERSION/debian/patches/` subfolder. There's a bunch of `.diff` and `.patch` files there. When I look at one of the `.diff`s, I see that the patches haven't been applied.  So then I try to run `quilt push -a` to apply the patches. It returns that

> "the patch ... is already applied; check your series file"

for each patch. But it clearly isn't when I check the sources.

Also after reading `debian/README.source`, it suggests to run the target `patch` in `debian/rules`. But I don't see any `patch:` in the `rules` file and running `make patch` gives

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'patch'.  Stop.
```

So I don't understand: are the patches in `debian/patches/` applied in the binary `$PKG-VERSION.deb` even though the source files are unpatched? And how do I patch the sources? I could just write a bash script to loop over and run `patch` over `debian/patches/*.diff` but surely that's not how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patches in debian/patches are applied during the build process. So the binaries will be based on the patches.

See https://wiki.debian.org/debian/patches.